# How do I fix the bibliography style abbrv to make my title italic and journal name upright?

Tags: bibtex

In the overleaf website abbrv makes the title italic and the journal name upright, like this:

[image]

When I use this style on my paper (\bibliographystyle{abbrv}), it seems to do the opposite: it makes the title upright and the journal name italic. I took this screenshot from my paper

[image]

How is it possible to change this?

Comment: Your claim that the `abbrv` bib style "makes the title italic and the journal name upright" would appear to be incorrect, at least for entries of type `@article`. For sure, in both `[1]` and `[24]`, the `journal` fields ("Annalen der Physik" and "Int'l Journal of Production reseearch", respectively) are both rendered in italics whereas the `title` fields are both rendered in upright letters. Also, `[2]` and `[3]` do not appear to be based on entries of type `@article`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks. I didn't read [1] since it wasn't in English. I just read [2] and [3]. So I guess my question is...how can I make the type "article" this way as well (that's what I need to do to submit my paper).

Comment: This "I want to apply consistent formatting to all entry types" desire is voiced regularly on this site. E.g., [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/614191/5001), [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/506053/5001), and [more](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/417918/5001). In such situations, the generally given piece of advice is, "there is absolutely no need for, or value in, making things -- such as entries of type `@article` and `@book` -- that are intrinsically different look the same".

Comment: Are you familiar with what [Ralph Waldo Emerson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ralph_Waldo_Emerson) had to say about (foolish) [consistency](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/353571-a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds-adored)?

Comment: @Mico I normally wouldn't care about changing the format, but this seems to be the format that the journal wants. I don't want to submit something incorrect, so is there a way to change how abbrv deals with articles?

Comment: My urgent advice is not to mess with the innards of the file `abbrv.bst`. Are you using the `abbrv` bib style because the submission instructions of the pubisher in question include such an instruction? If not, do they provide suggestions for which bibliography style (bst) to employ? If a journal has non-standard formatting instructions for bibliographic items, a reasonable journal should provide a bst file that implements said instructions...

Comment: @Mico Unfortunately, they do not have a bst file. I checked a sample that they have and they seem to write the bibliography within the tex file (using bibitem). If there isn't a solution for me (using abbrv), then I will have to write each of the my references the way they did which will take a long time. So my question: is there a quick fix that I can do on abbrv?

Comment: Simple answer: No. Longer, and hopefully more helpful answer: I recommend you become familiar with the `makebst` utility, which is part of the [custom-bib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib) package. The utility lets you create a bespoke bst file that incorporates all formatting requirements.

Comment: For an example of bst modification see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122768/bibtex-make-title-italic-rest-upright. That is for `alpha.bst` but it should be very similar for `abbrv.bst`.

Comment: Here is one for `elsarticle-harc`, which is already a numeric style: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376020/bibtex-how-can-i-make-the-journals-books-etc-titles-italic-using-elsearticle. But I advise you to double check if this is indeed "what the journal wants" or that you might have misunderstood the requirements, as this requirement is rather non-standard. Furthermore, journals are usually ok with some minor deviations from their guidelines, if the paper gets accepted then they will do their own copy-editing to make sure everything conforms to their format.

Comment: @Marjin Unfortunately I just figured out that they don't support biblatex. So I will have to use add the referenes within the tex file. Anyways, thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @Artus I'm not sure what you mean by "they don't support biblatex". The suggestions in my links but also the links from Mico are for BibTeX, not BibLaTeX. And when a journal doesn't support BibTeX they always _do_ support including files produced by BibTeX (i.e., `.bbl` files), or if they don't even support that then they support copy-pasting from a `.bbl` file into your `.tex` file directly. So you still can use solutions for BibTeX that change the use of italics compared to default styles.